# converting List<List<string[]>> into string [][][] in c#

Tags: c#, web-services

When creating webservices, in c#, I have found it very useful to pass back jagged arrays, i.e. string[][]

I also found a neat trick to build these in a simple way in my code, which was to create a List and convert it by doing a ToArray() call.

e.g.

```
public string[][] myws() {
    List<string[]> output = new List<string[]>();
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

I would like to be able to employ a similar solution, but I can't think how to do something similar with a 3 level jagged array or string[][][], without resorting to loops and such.

Regards
Martin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get there by doing a `Select()` which converts each inner `List<string>` to an array using  `ToArray()`, and then converting those results using `ToArray()`:

```
        var x = new List<List<string[]>>();

        string[][][] y = x.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

And so on for as many levels deep as you'd want to go.

Comment: to be clear this isn't avoiding "loops and such", it's just burying the implementation of those loops inside of LINQ.  it's the right answer though.

Comment: @RobertLevy: True, it only *avoids* loops in the sense of having a cleaner appearance, internally, yes it still loops -- unfortunately any conversion from a list to an array at some point performs loops either explicitly or implicitly...

Comment: @RobertLevy: Actually, `List<T>.ToArray()` just does an `Array.Copy()` since the underlying storage for a `List<T>` is already an `Array`.

Comment: @DStanley: Good to know, I forgot List<T> already had a ToArray() implementation...

Comment: @DStanley And that will, at some level, still be performing a loop.  It might be a more efficient loop if it's at a lower level, but at some point each bit of data in the list is being copied to a new location.  The point here is mostly that the operation is, at best, O(sizeOfDimention^numberOfDimensions).  It's not O(1) the way some people think that it might be.